# Case when based on first few characters

Tags: sql, join, case, teradata

I have Table A that looks like this:

```
Name   Phone
John   1111231234
Joe    1111231235
Jack   2221231234
Jenny  2224321234
Jody   3323214211
```

and Table B that looks like this:

```
AreaCode
111         
111
222
222
```

How do I return a result that looks like this? I essentially want to return AreaCode if the first 3 numbers/characters from the column 'Phone' exist in the column 'AreaCode' in table B...

```
Name   Phone       AreaCode
John   1111231234  111
Joe    1111231235  111
Jack   2221231234  222
Jenny  2224321234  222
Jody   3323214211  null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join to table b, joining where the phone starts with the areacode:

```
select
    name,
    phone,
    areacode
from tableA
left join tableB on phone like concat(areacode, '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used distinct to avoid repeated areacodes that will bring you duplicated results.
If you store areacode an phone as numeric you can omit the cast

```
select a.*, b.AreaCode
from TableA a left join (select distinct areacode from tableb) b 
    on left(cast(a.Phone as varchar(20)),3)=cast(b.AreaCode as varchar(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

In teradata, you may need something like this

```
select
    name,
    phone,
    areacode
from tableA
left join tableB on SUBSTRING(phone FROM 1 FOR 3) = areacode
```

Answer (score 0):

As some values in column `phone` exceeds the max allowed limit for  `INTEGER` i.e. `2147483647`, so i assume that `BIGINT` is the datatype. In this case below is the query that will return your desired result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name,
                t1.Phone,
                t2.areacode
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON substring(t1.Phone
                          FROM 11
                          FOR 3) = t2.areacode
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

`substring` impliticitly cast `bigint` to 20 space variable character left justified as `bigint` requires 20 character, so the starting point for `substring` is `11`. Also teradata implicitly compare `character` with `INT`, so no need to `cast` `areacode`

Other option is to use `trim` before `substring` to remove leading spaces as below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name,
                t1.Phone,
                t2.areacode
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON substring(trim(t1.Phone)
                          FROM 1
                          FOR 3) = t2.areacode
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

`DISTINCT` is used to avoid duplicates, as area code has duplicate values, so joining it to the phone record table will create duplicate rows.

**Result:**

```
Name    Phone             areacode
----------------------------------
Jack    2,221,231,234     222
Jenny   2,224,321,234     222
Joe     1,111,231,235     111
John    1,111,231,234     111
Jody    3,323,214,211     ?
```

*P.S. As `substring` and `trim` functions are same in Teradata and MySQL, you can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/NFQ23137)***

Hope this will help :-)